# In Selenium IDE, how to make a wait command in selenium test until a browser reloads?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have used the Selenium IDE to generate some code and I am now i want to put a wait command until the browser reloads after a button click.  For example:

```
public void TheGetTest()
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/");
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[contains(text(),'Get Quotes')])[2]")).Click();
}
```

After the Click command, I want to see what URL is loaded.  Is this possible or do I have to have to use some element on the page to look for?

```
WebDriverWait wait5 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement")));
```

How would this code be used if the dynamic element is the page itself?

Answer (score 0):

Its been some time since i used selenium.
But maybe you can use a javascript function to determine if the document is in ready state again.

wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));